# Power series expansion of a function involving Hypergeometric2F1

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I need to expand (around $z=0$) the following function:

$\qquad q(z)^n= \exp(- i n  \pi\tau(z)) \qquad n \in N$

where:

$\qquad \tau(z)=i\frac{\rm{Hypergeometric2F1}[1/2, 1/2, 1, 1 - z]}{\rm{Hypergeometric2F1}[1/2, 1/2, 1, z]}$.

Using `Series` works just fine for `n = 1`. However, for any larger `n` it doesn't expand it at all.

Any suggestions?

```
τ[z_] := I Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/2, 1, 1 - z]/Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1/2, 1, z]

q[z_, n_] := E^(n*I*π*τ[z])

Series[q[z, 3], {z, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

```
 Series[q[z, n], {z, 0, 5}]

 (* E^(-((n π EllipticK[1 - z])/EllipticK[z])) *)
```

Expand the exponent first:

```
Normal[Series[-((n π EllipticK[1 - z])/EllipticK[z]), {z, 0, 5}]]

 (* (n z)/2 + (13 n z^2)/64 + (23 n z^3)/192 + (2701 n z^4)/32768 + (5057 n z^5)/81920 -
    n (4 Log[2] - Log[z]) *)
```

The last term is equal to

```
Simplify[Exp[-n (4 Log[2] - Log[z])]]

(* 16^-n z^n *)
```

Now expand:

```
16^-n z^n * Normal[Series[Exp[(n z)/2 + (13 n z^2)/64 + (23 n z^3)/192 +
(2701 n z^4)/32768 + (5057 n z^5)/81920], {z, 0, 5}]]
```

For `n = 3`, we have:

```
% /. n -> 3

(* z^3/4096 + (3 z^4)/8192 + (111 z^5)/262144 + (235 z^6)/524288 + (61227 z^7)/134217728 +
   (122157 z^8)/268435456 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same idea as @VaclavKotesovec, just packaged a little differently.

```
qseries[n_, o_] := (z/16)^n Series[q[z, n] Exp[n(Log[16] - Log[z])], {z, 0, o-n}];
qseries[3, 10] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{z^3}{4096}+\frac{3 z^4}{8192}+\frac{111 z^5}{262144}+\frac{235
>    z^6}{524288}+\frac{61227 z^7}{134217728}+\frac{122157 z^8}{268435456}+\frac{3857001
>    z^9}{8589934592}+\frac{7563825 z^{10}}{17179869184}+O\left(z^{11}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

What has not been mentioned in any of the previous answers is that the [nome $q$](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticNomeQ/) is built into *Mathematica*:

```
(EllipticNomeQ[z] + O[z]^9)^3
   z^3/4096 + (3 z^4)/8192 + (111 z^5)/262144 + (235 z^6)/524288 + (61227 z^7)/134217728 +
   (122157 z^8)/268435456 + (3857001 z^9)/8589934592 + (7563825 z^10)/17179869184 + O[z]^11
```

---

**Important note**: for some reason this expansion is broken in version 11.1; this works correctly in version 11.2 and versions earlier than 11.1, however.

Comment: It will work again in 11.2 (maybe you knew that).

Comment: "Maybe" is the operative word.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you may also be able to use the purely numerical approach:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

Chop@Normal@NSeries[q[z, 3], {z, 0, 10}, Radius -> 0.1]

(*
==> 
0.000244141 z^3 + 0.000366211 z^4 + 0.000423431 z^5 + 
 0.000448227 z^6 + 0.000456177 z^7 + 0.00045507 z^8 + 
 0.000449014 z^9 + 0.000440273 z^10
*)
```

Here, I had to adjust the `Radius` option to get an expansion that doesn't break down at zero. With this choice, all terms agree with the other answers if you convert their coefficients with `N`.