# Series Expansion of EllipticNomeQ differs from older Mathematica Version

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I am trying to follow the numerical approach on how to calculate `EllipticE` and `EllipticK` following [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226331661_Fast_computation_of_complete_elliptic_integrals_and_Jacobian_elliptic_functions). In there on approach uses the `EllipticNomeQ`, namely

$$q(m) = \exp\left({{ -\pi K(m)}\over{ K(1 - m) }}\right)$$

but with

$$\lambda(m) =  { {1 - \sqrt{k'}} \over { 1 + \sqrt{k'}}}$$

and

$$k' = \sqrt{1 - m}$$

what is required is  a series expansion of $q(m(\lambda))$ with respect to $\lambda$. The paper suggests to use

```
Series[ EllipticNomeQ[ 1 - ((1 - 2x) / (1 + 2x))^4 ], {x, 0, 30}]
```

Unfortunately, this does not provide useful coefficients. For the expansion to order 1 it provides

```
SeriesData[x, 0, { InverseSeries[0, 0]^4, 64 InverseSeries[0, 0]^3 Derivative[0, 1][InverseSeries][ 0, 0]}, 0, 2, 1]
```

Obviously, it was working in 2012 which also can be seen on the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002103). Fortunately, the OEIS  provides code to calculate the coefficients directly, but the fact that the expansion is not working is unsatisfying.

The expected result (see OEIS) is $x + 2 x^5 + 15 x^9 + 150 x^{13} + 1707 x^{17} + \mathcal{O}(x^{21})$

Which trick am I missing?

**Additional Info**

- Mathematica is Version 11.1
- [Related Question 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151190/7608)
- [Related Question2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139388/7608)

Comment: I get the expected result in V13.0.1. (I'm confused about which version you're using and which is the older one referred to in the title, assuming "Mathematic" is a typo for "Mathematica".)

Comment: I also get the expected result in version 13; this might have been a bug that got fixed.

Comment: V11.3.0 also gives the correct result.

Comment: @MichaelE2 lol, changed the title. By old version I am referring to the version that was used at the time the paper was written. 2011 it was likely version 8 and most likely working.

Comment: @J.M. I checked at home on version 13.0.1 for Linux ARM and it works as well. So It might be a "bug" similar to the one [linked above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139388/7608)

Comment: Thanks to all who commented. That was very helpful. Would be nice to figure what caused the problem, but the is not super important. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** For revised question:

With v13.0.1 or 12.0.0 I get the same result as shown below. I don't have access to earlier versions.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

f[x_] = EllipticNomeQ[1 - ((1 - 2 x)/(1 + 2 x))^4];

f2[x_] = Series[f[x], {x, 0, 30}] // Normal

(* x + 2 x^5 + 15 x^9 + 150 x^13 + 1707 x^17 + 20910 x^21 + 
 268616 x^25 + 3567400 x^29 *)

Plot[{f[x], f2[x]}, {x, -.75, .75},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.8, .2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my mistake from fiddling around with the problem (copied some intermediate stuff). Series is actually around `0` not `1`. Changed the post accordingly

Comment: In 13 on Windows 10 `Series[EllipticNomeQ[1 - ((1 - 2 x)/(1 + 2 x))^4], {x, 0, 30}]` results in $$x+2 x^5+15 x^9+150 x^{13}+1707 x^{17}+20910 x^{21}+268616 x^{25}+3567400 x^{29}+O\left(x^{31}\right) .$$

Comment: I have `$Version ->"11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"`...putting your code I get the `InverseSeries[0,0]` stuff from above. Well, screams for an update. I'll check on my Pi4 at home. :)

Comment: Checked on my Pi4: Version 13.0.1. for Linux ARM 32-bit and also got the expected result. So it seems to be a problem with 11.1.